# Slider overflow responsive

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, slider

I'm working with this slider, all works great but why on small screen 
(less than 480) or on responsive view it don't run?!
how can i fix this problem?!

More details in the fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/tMxp5/1/

```
  $(function() {
   var c = 1, 
       timeOut,
       fit,
       isStopped = false, 
       boxw = $('.box').outerWidth(true),
       boxh = $('.box').outerHeight(true),
       boxn = $('.box').length;

    $('#slider').width(boxw*boxn);
    $('#gal, #slider').height(boxh);
    //////////////////////////////////
    function measure() {
        var winw = $(window).width();
        fit = Math.ceil(winw/boxw)-1; // math ceil -1 to get the number of COMPLETELY visible boxes
        $('#gal').width(winw);

        $('#t').html('Boxw='+boxw+' Boxh='+boxh+' Winw='+winw+' VisibleBoxes='+ fit);
    }
    measure();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        measure();
    });
    //////////////////////////////////    
    function b(){
       cc = (c === 1) ? $('.prev').hide() : $('.prev').show();
       ccc =(c >= boxn/fit) ? $('.next').hide() : $('.next').show();    
    }    
    $('.btn').hide();
    /////////////////////////////////

    function a(cb){ 
       $('#slider').animate({left: '-'+ (boxw*fit)*(c-1) },800, cb);
    }
    ////////////////////////////////
    function auto() {
    if(isStopped){ return };
       clearTimeout(timeOut);  
       timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
       $('.btn').hide();            
       c++;             
       if (c >= (boxn/fit)+1) {
          c = 1;
        }            
          a(function(){
             auto();
          });   
       }, 2000);
    }
    auto();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $('.next').click(function() {
           c++;
           b();
           a();
        });
        $('.prev').click(function() {
           c--;
           b();
           a();
        });
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $('#gal').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {    
       ( e.type === 'mouseenter' ) ?
       ( isStopped=true, b(), clearTimeout(timeOut) ) :
       ( isStopped=false, auto() );
    });

});
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your measure function set the number of visible boxes to 0

try changing the measure function to:

```
function measure() {
    var winw = $(window).width();
    fit = Math.ceil(winw/boxw)-1; // math ceil -1 to get the number of COMPLETELY visible boxes
    $('#gal').width(winw);

    if (fit == 0) fit = 1;
    $('#t').html('Boxw='+boxw+' Boxh='+boxh+' Winw='+winw+' VisibleBoxes='+ fit);
}
```

And it should fix your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/tMxp5/270/

Comment: Another question...in this case the width of a single div is of 350 px         But if every div has a different width, how can i stop the slide at the start of every div?!

Comment: I think you may have to use a different plugin for that as this one seems to work on a one size box sliding animation - all the calculations are based around the size of the boxes being the same.  The bit that does the animation is in this function: `function a(cb)`, you would need to calculate the size of the current box and change the animation to minus that width.  Perhaps mock up an example in your fiddle and then post another question

Comment: thanks a lot again! i will post another question with a new fiddle !